# Duplicate entries with same insert statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am having difficult with duplicate entries in SQL Server 2008 R2. Due to the nature of the program, I have been told unique constraints are not an option.

Can someone please assist as I have tried a For Insert Trigger but no luck.

Table structure:

```
col1 - identity
col2 - filename
col3 - date
col4 - filetype
col5 - process
col6 - userid
col7 - info
```

When I run this `insert` the first time, it enters both the entries. Which I do not want:

```
insert into table(filename, filetype,process, userid)
values
  ('test9','import','view','tester'),
  ('test9','import','view','tester')
```

The entry is now in the table twice the only difference is the identity column.

```
Identity     Filename   Date          Filetype     Process    Userid    Info
17           Test9      2014-01-31    Import       View       test      null
18           Test9      2014-01-31    Import       View       test      null
```

When I run the exact same insert the second time it then does not insert as it then sees it as a duplicate. Why does it not see it as a duplicate the first time?

Here is the trigger that I created:

```
Create trigger check_duplicates
on table
for insert
as 
  if not exist (select p.filename, p.date
                from table p, inserted i
                where p.filename = i.filename and p.date = i.date)
   insert into table
   select filename, date, filetype, process, userid, info
   from inserted
else 
  raiserror('Duplicate file exist',16,1)

rollback
end
```

Thank you

Comment: `inserted` is a table not a single record, you have to join it with the insert-table.

Comment: You need to put the `raiserror` and `rollback` in the `else` case into a `BEGIN .... END` code block - otherwise, the `ROLLBACK` will be executed every time the trigger runs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to check if there are duplicates in the inserted-rows itself, so a table-scan is not sufficient. You could compare `COUNT(*)..` with `COUNT(DISTINCT FileName,Date)FROM INSERTED`.

You also have to replace `FOR INSERT` with `INSTEAD OF INSERT`:

Try this:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[check_duplicates]
on [dbo].[TableName]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
as 
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.TableName T 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I 
        ON T.FileName= I.FileName AND T.Date= I.Date
    )
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) =
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(FileName, Date)) FROM INSERTED)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.TableName 
        SELECT FileName, Date, filetype, process, userid, info 
        FROM INSERTED
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('Duplicate file exist',16,1) 
END
```

However, you have to create an update-trigger as well.

**Edit**: Here is a <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34391/2/1)</kbd>

Comment: Tried the above and it still creates a duplicate entry. Can you please explain what the update trigger would be for. This is my first go at these triggers.

Comment: @user1854183: i haven't tried above so i must admit that i'm not sure if it works, maybe it's more complicated than necessary. You have to provide an update trigger with the same rule because someone could modify a record so that it will become a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong, but it still inserts both entries the first time and second time round only tells me that the file exists.

Comment: @user1854183: have a look again ;)

Comment: I get two error when trying to create the trigger:                     Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Stop_Duplicates, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Stop_Duplicates, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: @user1854183: i have created a simple test-table and above trigger. As far as i can see it works. Here is a sql-fiddle with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22314/4/1 (play around with the last `SELECT '123';`)

Comment: @user1854183: now i know what was wrong. My test contained only one column in the `COUNT(DISTINCT cols)` whereas you need to check multiple columns. You can use `DISTINCT CHECKSUM`. I have edited my answer (hopefully the last time).

Comment: Thank you. It works beautifully!! developers are all happy as we did not have to use constraints.